# Is there a way to construct an object using a string representation of its constituent parts without using any reflection for this particular step?

Tags: .net, reflection

Let's assume I have some `MyObject obj` object and want to access a property of that object such as `obj.SomeCollection.SomeProperty`. Is it possible to get that property on this object by combining obj and .SomeCollection.SomeProperty represented as a string without invoking any of the reflection functions for this particular step?

UPDATE: The reason why I'm trying to avoid reflection is because of a huge performance hit. Basically, I will use reflection in order to extract the string reperesentation of its constituent parts and store them in some kind of dictionary which will be reused from that point on, thus avoiding using reflection every time I need an access to object's properties. The reason why I'm so worried about performance is because I need to use this process, if it exists, for enterprise-level system unit tests. With reflection this usage becomes unrealistic as it could take up to an hour to run these tests. Hope this explains my position.

Comment: From what you're trying to accomplish, reflection sounds like the perfect tool.  Any particular reason you're trying to avoid it?

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to avoid reflection is because of a huge performance hit. Basically, I will use reflection in order to extract the string reperesentation of its constituent parts and store them in some kind of dictionary which will be reused from that point on, thus avoiding using reflection every time I need an access to object's property.

Comment: How much of a performance hit, though? Assuming you cache the reflection result, the performance shouldn't be that much slower.

Comment: Well, I need to use this process for enterprise-level system unit tests. So, if I went reflection route, I would need to use it for probably hundreds of objects some of which are very complex. So, the performance hit math is not on my side. That's why I was thinking that if there was a way to save whatever class's structure in some sort of dictionary prior to running unit tests and then use it to navigate the object created during run-time, then this process could be sped up significantly enough to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I tend to agree with @Scott (why not use Reflection, perfect for this...) if you can serialize the object to XML, or even better an XML DataSet, you can use a variety of options to negotiate the object with strings as identifiers.

**Following edit posted following @Ukraine Train 2 comments re: performance**

@Ukraine Train, Neither reflection nor XML serialization are real performance dogs. "Performance" depends on how many iterations you are wanting to process and how fast you want to process them. Once you go through the instantiation of the object through reflection or XML serialization the object is then 'in memory' and all access will be via pointers. How many objects you want to reside in memory at a time, how long you want them to live are all strategic decisions I don't have enough information to advise you on.

If you want to be able to interrogate the object using string identifiers, your choices are pretty much reflection or serialization. I believe you are overestimating the performance hit of reflection when you call it '*huge*'. The fastest thing you can accomplish is nothing, anything else takes time and resources.

Comment: Shouldn't this step be as bad performance-wise as using reflection?

Comment: Please, let me rephrase this question. How bad is this step performance-wise? Is it comparable to reflection in that respect?

Comment: My coworkers wrote a class that performed a deep copy of object using a reflection. They spent 3 weeks on it and the soluion was very nice and elegant. The problem was that it was extremely slow. So, 3 weeks of work went down the drain. What I'm trying to undertake here would use reflection far more extensively. So, I'm very concerned about it.

Comment: One of the advantages of XML serialization is that you can specify which attributes you want to serialize and how deep you want to go. Not knowing more about your scenario, I think this is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `dynamic` keyword, new in C# 4.  This allows you to use methods and properties of an object not known at compile-time.  You can read about it on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), but the basic usage is:

```
public static void Main()
{
     // Instantiate or retrieve your object into memory
     dynamic obj = RetrieveCustomObject();

     // Invoke methods on object not known at compile time
     int id = obj.Id;
     bool result = obj.DoWork();
}
```

As long as the instance methods exist and can be resolved at runtime time, they will execute successfully.  If they don't exist, a runtime exception will be thrown.

This doesn't use string representations of the object's methods as you requested, but it may be worth considering anyway.  In terms of performance, this *should* compare well with other methods described.  However, you should profile your application to validate whichever method you choose.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be strings as long as it can be stored in some dictionary and used later to construct an object several levels deep.